# does the tabview renders components on swipe only?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-tab-view

The screen i am working on needs some tab navigation . its working great but there is one problem. It renders the component on swipe only when i press on the tab i want to go to . it does not do anything.
Ex: I am on tab number 3 and i want to go to tab 1. 
If i click on tab 1 , nothing happens . i have to swipe to it passing tab 2 in the process .
I don't want that . Here's my code.

```
<TabView
   navigationState={this.state}
   renderScene={this.renderScene}
   onIndexChange={index => this.setState({ index })}
   initialLayout={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width }}
 />
```

render scene function

```
renderScene = ({ route, jumpTo }) => {
    switch (route.key) {
      case 'activity':
        return <ProfileActivity jumpTo={jumpTo} />;
      case 'circles':
        return <ProfileCircles jumpTo={jumpTo} />;
      case 'friends':
        return <ProfileFriends jumpTo={jumpTo} />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };
```

state

```
  state = {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { key: 'activity', title: 'Activity' },
      { key: 'circles', title: 'Circles' },
      { key: 'friends', title: 'Friends' }
    ]
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use lazy prop! 
If you want to render all tabs at once then you should pass false to lazy prop otherwise pass true.

See the documenation
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @AmrAboElenin Please explain more!

Comment: i can swipe from one component to another but when i press the tab title to go to that component nothing happens

Comment: @AmrAboElenin Did you try `SceneMap` ?

Answer (score 0):

lazy props works when you tap on the tab right next another one, but it does not work for the scenario when you have a lot of tabs with the props `scrollEnabled` and change from the first tab to the last one. To fix this I used this logic, which also garantuees this scenario and renders at most two screen at once:

```
const renderScene = ({ route }) => {
    const shouldRenderRouteScreen = Math.abs(index - routes.indexOf(route)) < 2
    if (shouldRenderRouteScreen) {
      return <ScreenExample />;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
 }


   <TabView
      lazy
      navigationState={{ index, routes }}
      renderScene={renderScene}
      renderTabBar={(props) => (
         <TabBar {...props} scrollEnabled={true} />
      ...
  />
```